# Spring-Boot Spring-Batch MultiResourceItemReader to merge files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to follow the simple [Spring Batch tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/), but I want to read two files instead of a single file when creating a `Person` object.

I've been looking through examples, and all the examples I've seen that use two or more files explicitly use multiple files that follow the same format. In my case I have two files, a `firstname.csv` and a `lastname.csv`. I'd like to read from them (preferably in one step) to create my `Person`.

So the example shows:

```
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

And what I've got thus far:

```
  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<Person> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<Person>();
    ClassPathResource[] resources = {new ClassPathResource("firstnames.csv"), new ClassPathResource("lastnames.csv")};
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resources);

    // Magic here ...

    return multiResourceItemReader;
  }
```

How do I merge these files as I've described, instead of the expected all files with same-format way?

Comment: does the n-th line of firstname.csv contain the relative n-th lastname.csv or data are not guarantee to be synchronized?

Comment: this is possible only if there is sync in both files - like nth record in first file matches with nth record in seconn file

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the file contain the same number of rows and for row N in both files the data is for the same person.

First create two `ItemReader`s one for first names, the other for surnames.  Then merge the results of the two items readers together.

Like this:

```
public ItemReader<Person> getPersonReader {
    final ItemReader<Person> firstNameReader = firstNameReader();
    final ItemReader<Person> lastNameReader = lastNameReader();

    return new ItemReader<Person>(){ 
        public Person read() {
            return mergeFirstLast(firstNameReader.read(), lastNameReader.read());
        }
    };

}

public Person mergeFirstLast(Person first, Person last) {
    // do merge logic here
    return ...
}

public ItemReader<Person> firstNameReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("firstname.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "firstName" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
public ItemReader<Person> lastNameReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("lastname.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "lastName" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is can be done reading the second file in Item processor -

Your -reader is of type - firtsNameReader

Your -Processor is of type - firstNameReader which returns object having - first name and last name

Your writer will be of type object --writting first name and last name into new file

```
Class ItemProcessor


public static int readLines=0;

Public void process(firstName){

String lastName;

ItemProcessor.readLines++;

FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("lastName.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
for(int i = 0; i < readLines.readLines; ++i){
  br.readLine();
  }
 lastName = br.readLine();



 System.out.println (firstName);
  System.out.println (lastName);

  NewObject obj = new NewObject();

  obj.setLastName(lastName);
  obj.setFirstName(firstName);

  return obj;

  }
```